# iOS how to load certificate file(crt) match in app to connect https server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, openssl, certificate

I have write the https connection.

I am self signed the certificate file.

So I generate the keystore and crt file. The keystore file is using the tomcat and direct to use the https server.

The the crt file can download from server to install in the iPhone device.

But now I want to wrapping the crt file in the my application code.

How can I load the crt file in app and encrypt data , then the server can check the key and the keystore is match.

I don't what to download crt file from server install in the iPhone, it will more the setup to upload or download data.

my https method is below:

```
 -(void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler{

 NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition =      NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
__block NSURLCredential *credential = nil;

if( [challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    MYLog(@"server is trust certificate credential:%@",credential);
    if(credential){
        disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    }else{

        disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;


         }
     }else{
         disposition =      NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge;

     }

     if(completionHandler){
         completionHandler(disposition,credential);
     }

 }
```

Thank you very much.